# Can I place a div over another div that is set `position: absolute`?

Tags: html, css

I have this page and I'd like to be able to include a pop-up over the page.

https://bl.ocks.org/wdtglrn/raw/1ccf61e1912717d868dfe25dfde29bbe/402a25663023a41702fafe29e3f74d6077eb459f/

If you click discover, you'll see the pop-up is underneath the three titles.

The titles are in a container that is a sibling to the pop-up.

```
//pop up
<section id="header" class ="collapsed">
  <h3>About</h3>
  <div id="dismiss">OK</div>
</section>

//titles
<div id="visual">
        <h3 id="channel"> Which channel brought the most customers? </h3>
        <h3 id="performance"> Which channel offered the best performance?</h3>
</div>
```

I have the pop-up set to position `absolute`. I also have the titles set to position `absolute` with `left: 52%` so that they will stay on the left side of the screen at just the right point.

Is it possible to get one absolute div to cover over another one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give your `#header` div a `z-index`:

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 65%;
    top: 1%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Or move it to the end of the page after `#visual`. Read up on [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) and [stacking without the z-index property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
z-index: 1;
```

to your class

```
#header:not(.collapsed) {
```